# Unsure of how to fix invalid cursor state

Tags: java, sql, database

I've been trying to figure out what's wrong with the resultset for the past 2 hours. I'm trying to connect to a MS Access database, and I have a similar working method that is almost exactly the same except the sql statements are different. Since the sql statement highlights everything in the table, I assumed the resultset would work, but apparently not. Can anyone give me a pointer?

Here's my code:

```
    public static Video[] searchdatabase(String videoname, String uploadername, int likes, int dislikes, int favorites, int subscribers,int views, String category) throws SQLException
{
    String sql = "SELECT COUNT(VideoID) AS Num FROM tblYoutubeVideo";
Statement stmt = conn.createStatement();
ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(sql);

rs.next();

int numrows = rs.getInt("Num");
    System.out.println("Numrows: "+numrows);
Video[] arr2 = new Video[numrows];

    sql = ("SELECT * FROM tblVideo, tblUploader WHERE tblVideo.Video_Name LIKE '"+videoname+"' AND tblUploader.Uploader_Name LIKE '"+uploadername+"'AND tblVideo.Views>"+views+" AND tblVideo.Likes>"+likes+" AND tblVideo.Dislikes<"+dislikes+" AND tblVideo.Favorites>"+favorites+" AND tblUploader.Subscribers>"+subscribers+"ORDER BY (Likes+(Views*0.5)+(Favorites*2)+(Subscribers*2))-2");
System.out.println(sql);
    stmt = conn.createStatement();
rs = stmt.executeQuery(sql);


    for (int i=0;i<arr2.length;i++)
    {
        rs.next();
        int uploaderid2 = rs.getInt("UploaderID");
        String uploader_name2 = rs.getString("Uploader_name");
        int subscribers2 = rs.getInt("Subscribers");
        int videoid2 = rs.getInt("VideoID");
        String video_name2 = rs.getString("Video_name");
        int favorites2 = rs.getInt("Favorites");
        String category2 = rs.getString("Category");
        int views2 = rs.getInt("Views");
        int likes2 = rs.getInt("Likes");
        int dislikes2 = rs.getInt("Dislikes");

        Video temp = new Video(uploaderid2, uploader_name2, subscribers2, videoid2, video_name2, favorites2, category2, views2, likes2, dislikes2);

        System.out.println(arr2[i]);
        arr2[i] = temp;
    }


    return arr2;

}
```

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Aside from anything else, you should fix your indentation, and use prepared statements to avoid SQL injection attacks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suspect the problem is here:

```
rs.next();
```

You're ignoring the return value of `next()`, which tells you whether or not you've actually moved onto another valid row, or whether you've reached the end of the results. You're currently *assuming* that you have `numrows` results, even though `numrows` is the number of rows in `tblYoutubeVideo` and your actual query is filtered.

I would personally remove the first query completely - just use an `ArrayList<Video>` instead, and instead of your `for` loop, have:

```
List<Video> videos = new ArrayList<Video>();
while (rs.next())
{
    ... read data ...
    videos.add(new Video(...));
}
```

Additionally, not that your current code is vulnerable to [SQL injection attacks](http://bobby-tables.com). Rather than include values directly in your SQL, you should use parameterized SQL with `PreparedStatement`. You specify placeholders in the SQL itself, and set the parameter values in the statement.

Additionally, you should be closing the statement and result set in `finally` blocks. (I'd personally close the connection, too - use a connection pool so that you can always open the connection, use it, and close it.)

Comment: Thanks for this, I'm busy changing the code via your recommendations. I really appreciate the detailed post, and I will hopefully be able to get this working now :)